# PHP foreach while handling chunks

Tags: php, xml, buffer

I'm currently trying to handle a large XML file (1,5 gb),
Currently it's opening in chunks

```
    $handle = fopen($url, "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");
        if ($handle) {
            while (!feof($handle)) {
            $chunk = fgets($handle, 4096);
            // echo each chunk
            echo $chunk;
        }
    fclose($handle);
    }
```

Instead of echo'ing this chunk, I'd like to save up each line untill `</file>` is found. therefor:

```
$handle = fopen($url, "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $chunk = fgets($handle, 4096);
        // echo '<xmp>'.$buffer.'</xmp>';
            if (strpos($fullstring,'</file>') !== false) {
                // i should have everything between <file> and </file>

                // empty the $fullstring so it can fill with chunks again
                $fullstring = '';
            } else {
                $fullstring .= $chunk;
            }

    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Now I'd like to run this in a foreach loop. But instead of looping each found  it loops the same `<file></file>` for all `<file></file>`'s found.

How can I process each `<file>content</file>` found while loading the file in chunks?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If you need to parse a large XML file, I suggest combining XMLReader with DOM. Use XMLReader to get the chunk element node, expand it into DOM and use Xpath to fetch the details from the chunk.

```
$reader = new XMLReader;
$reader->open($file);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// look for the first chunk
while ($reader->read() && $reader->localName !== 'file') {
  continue;
}

// while you have an file element
while ($reader->localName === 'file') {
  $node = $reader->expand($dom);

  // $xpath->evaluate('expression', $node);
  // ...

  // move to the next chunk (next file sibling node)
  $reader->next('file');
}
```

Comment: I should run this code within the 'while (!feof($handle)) {' ?

Comment: No it is a different approach. It replaces your source. `XMLReader::open()` opens the file and will read it it node by node. Only `XMLReader:expand()` will read that node and its descendants into memory.

Comment: I'm not familiar with DOM nor XMLReader.
What's the appriate approach to echo an element found in 'file'?
Thank you for the assistance so far!

Comment: Use Xpath: `$xpath->evaluate('string(nodename)')`. Xpath is an expression language to fetch nodes and values from a DOM.  `echo $dom->saveXml($node);` will output the (outer) XML for a node.

Comment: echo $dom->saveXml($node); doesn't show me anything, neither does the error log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90107/discussion-between-sjef92-and-thw).

Comment: I nearly have the sollution, From the discussion,
How can I manage to retreive multiple nodes with the same name?(EAN Codes)

Comment: The last example shows that for the country codes: https://eval.in/436173 - you fetch the nodes with evaluate(), iterate them and read the values depending on the node type.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend PHP's DomDocument methods.  It is useful for parsing XML or HTML documents you might get with a file handle or `file_get_contents`, etc.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Also, PHP has a `array_chunk` capability http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: The main XML file is 1,5 gigabyte, It's nearly impossible to use file_get_contents, thus the chunking :)

Comment: Ok, understood. Still, to do any parsing I think the file needs read-in to (usually a string representation)

Comment: I don't quite understand your awnser, Can you ellaborate?

Comment: Basically, even though the file is large, to do any parsing (into elements that you can do something with) you need to read the file into a variable.