# PHP XML Reader Select child tag depending on Parent tag

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have a large XML file I am retrieving data from however I have several instances were the child elements are the same name and the XML reader stores the last one it come across:

```
<VehicleRemarketingBoat>
<MakeString>
Rodman Sportfisher
</MakeString>
</<VehicleRemarketingBoat>

<VehicleRemarketingEngine>
<MakeString>
Volvo
</MakeString>
</VehicleRemarketingEngine>
```

I would like to Detect the parent tag so I can then collect the data from the child tag.

**THIS ISSUE IS SOLVED CODE UPDATED TO FIXED VERSION:**

```
if($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->localName ==  'VehicleRemarketingBoat'){
         $node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($xml->expand(), true));
         $content['MakeString'] = $node->MakeString;

    }
if($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->localName ==  'VehicleRemarketingEngine'){
         $node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($xml->expand(), true));
         $content['EngineMake'] = $node->MakeString;
         $PreOwnedData[] = $content;
         var_dump($PreOwnedData);
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide some information about the error you get?

Comment: Well the error basically tells me that the array is empty when I attempt a Var_dump. Also when I do an Sql Insert it is empty. This first chunk of code does have information in it when I do a var_dump

Comment: Your question misses to much information to answer it. For a more generic approach see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668794/php-foreach-while-handling-chunks/32668941#32668941 You don't need to do all parsing with XMLReader, just the "records". After that expand the record into DOM and use Xpath.

Comment: Ok I managed to fix the problem I was having by mixing simpleXML in to the if statements, thanks for the link to the question that plus this questions [How to use XMLReader in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835177/how-to-use-xmlreader-in-php)